# Change The Users' Input To Bold Into A TextBox Without Change The Existing Content.

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I Have a TextBox(lets call it "**ViewTxtBox**") and a Button(lets call it "**BoldBtn**") who does the following:

• User input whatever he wants from the keyboard.

• Once the button clicked the font changes into bold.

BoldBtn Code:

```
ViewTxtBox.Font = new Font(ViewTxtBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Output If Clicked:

> "**Hello World I'm all bold and I don't want that**"

What I want to do is to change the users' input from the keyboard into bold without change the current content into bold.

Example:

> "Hello World"

-----------*"Clicks Button"*-------------

> "Hello World **I Pushed The Button And Went Bold"**

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with a RichTextBox. 
Use the selectionFont property to format the style before the text is added, and your button is clicked, change that selectionFont to Bold.

Comment: The thing is, I don't wanna select the font to make it bold.I know how to do that.What i want to do is, once I press my button(BoldBtn) the font will go bold (so i can "type" with bold format)BUT without that affecting the allready existing font as i explained above on my example..

Comment: Ok... and that RichTextBox does that. Have you even tried what i told you? The selectionFont property only affects the text that will be added.

Answer (score 0):

What's your use case?

The content of a box can have only one font defined by the *Font* attribute. So to achieve different font, you need different text box, or you need to redesign the full text box data template (or a new user control) to allow several string with different fonts (which seems a lot of trouble to me^^)

Comment: Well i got a printer and i want to print the content.(Using normal text box).
My app is sorta like a tester for the specific printer..